# Why did Firebase Realtime Database create empty child entries?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a simple app that takes in a comment and then posts the comment in a RecyclerView. But Firebase is creating thousands of empty children. I'm not sure why this is happening and would appreciate any help.

Here is a picture of what Firebase is doing.
[image]

Here is the method i'm using

```
private void postComment() {
    String title = editTitle.getText().toString();
    String content = editContent.getText().toString();

    Post post = new Post(title, content);

    databaseReference.push() // Creates unique id for comment
            .setValue(post);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Here is my Post Class

```
package com.example.androidfirebaserealtimedb;

public class Post {
// Member Variables
private String title, content;

// Constructors
public Post() { }

public Post(String title, String content) {
    this.title = title;
    this.content = content;
}

// Getters and Setters

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
}
```

Comment: Please share the code you use to write to the database.

Comment: What does your `Post` class look like?

Comment: When you submit the data, does you input something or leave it blank?

Comment: I put something in.

Comment: ok try to use logcat for the input. update the question later @BretWorthy

Comment: Actually, the database fills up before I save any information. @Ticherhaz

Comment: @BretWorthy so you stored the data manually? with empty string? (space)

Comment: @Ticherhaz I'm not even sure how that's happening because it's storing the data as soon as the app starts up.

Comment: @BretWorthy can you remov all the data stored and try to start apps again, lets see what happen

Comment: @Ticherhaz I tried to but there's so many that I had to delete the entire database and start anew. But it did the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was calling my postComment() inside the onDataChange(), so everytime it started up an empty comment was posting, and that would trigger my onDataChange to repeat constantly. @Ticherhaz, Thank you for helping me to continue looking at it. Your questioning pointed me to the issue, so thanks.